# How to (using console) put results in a txt. file or get complete results from a code that has already runned

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder, pythonxy

i'm currently solving optimization problems with python. One problem takes about 5hrs to solve which result will appear (sadly) in console but not completely since it's a very big list. I'm wondering right now if there is anyway to get the solution of the list completely while i'm waiting for the results (i've been waiting for 4hrs. now).

If there is a way i can get the complete result in the console after the code has runned, let me know. 
If there is a way via console to put the results in a .txt file or any type of readable file afterwards please let me know.

If there is no solution to this problem, let me know.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You mean, the code will terminate, as in the process will be done?

Comment: Yes you can put data in a text file. If you post code I can show you how to do it for your case. Side Note: WHAT on earth is taking 5 hours to run?

Comment: I'm doing Prim's method for MTS problems with 10000 nodes and 61700+ edges. How do you do that @EastonBornemeier.

Comment: yes @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @EastonBornemeier optimization problems, apparently. Which doesn't sound particularly crazy. In any event, I think the issue is that they have run some script, `python optimization_script.py`, but the output is simply the result of printing a giant `list`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there is much you can do except wait for it to finish, and re-write the code to output to a file instead of printing to the console. Maybe you can make your terminal scroll-back unlimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your python file is `myfile.py`, in order to redirect what is printed in this file run your file as:

```
python myfile.py > myfile.txt
```

Your printed list will be printed in  `myfile.txt`.

Comment: all i have to write in console is "python "nameofthescript".py > newfile.txt"?

Comment: the txt file will be in the same folder as the script?

Comment: Doing that you'll get your complete list at `myfile.txt`, yes.

Comment: If you run your program like `python myfile.py > myfile.txt` then yes.

Comment: thanks, ill check your answer if it works once the code is over.

Comment: You can run a file in two ways, using its **relative path** or its **absolute path**, respectively: `python myfile.py` and `python /home/documents/myfile.py`. Supposing you are at the directory (in your console) `/home/documents/` and that `myfile.py` is there. Then by running `python myfile.py > myfile.txt` will create `myfile.txt` in the same directory.

Comment: @DIEGOALFONSOARTUROMILLARDF this isn't something you can do *after* the code is done running. You need to do this *before*.

Answer (score 2):

say your script is called `yourscript.py`
and you have been running it in the console with: `python yourscript.py`

if you use this command:

```
python yourscript.py > newfile.txt
```

all of the output will go into newfile.txt

Comment: I mean, i do not have to import anything?

Comment: all i have to write in console is "python "nameofthescript".py > newfile.txt"?

Comment: exactly! if you make a little test python file that just has one line like: print("hello world") you can try running that from the console and then try running it with > newfile.txt - you'll see

Comment: @DIEGOALFONSOARTUROMILLARDF but that is how you are *suppose to run the script*. I'm not sure you can redirect once the process is alreaady running.

Answer (score 0):

pipe it into a file with the format you want
for **example your file name is xyz.py**

> In your python shell

```
 python xyz.py > myfile.txt
```

> Your output will now be in **myfile.txt**